# listening a store vs forceUpdate()

Tags: reactjs, flux

If I have five components on a page, which can get something from a store. They all are listening to a single store. For all components I create listeners in a store.

My question is - Can I use `forceUpdate()` instead of listener. Send something in a store and wait for update:

```
getInitialState: function() {
   return {val: Store.getFoo};
},
click: function(info) {
  Store.updateInfo(info, function() {
   this.forceUpdate();
  })
}
```

In store:

```
updateInfo: function(info, callback) {
   foo = info + someValue;
   callback()
}
```

But in documentation:

> Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only read from this.props and this.state in render(). This makes your application much simpler and more efficient

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use forceUpdate, but you *shouldn't*.

Your current approach is correct (not using forceUpdate).

If you have a common parent of these 5 listen for changes and pass data down to the children, the parent code will become bloated and you'll have 6 components (parent, 5 children) render when the store changes. Having more of these "container" components that listen to the store creates more isolation between components ("independent children") and is more performant because less components re-render when the store updates. Make sure you use shouldComponentUpdate, too.

If you'd like to learn more about "independent children" and higher-performance react, watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYzlpRvWZ6c

Comment: Sometimes `shouldComponentUpdate` is a pain in the ass when a component waits an object with >10 properties and only one can change.

Comment: Also I'm wondering why I shouldn't? I can get variable from store in `render` - `let var = Store.getVar();`. If I changed `var` in a store I can do `forceUpdate()`. I can do it with "independent children" too. `ForceUpdate` doesn't rerender childrens if I doesn't send new props. Less code, I don't need keep variable in `state`, only in a store

Comment: If it feels like your component depends on too much data you can use more sub-components, but then you have more components... there are trade-offs either way.

Comment: If you need to modify an object with 10+ properties, you can use `Object.assign` to create a new object and modify the property on the new one. Then inside the component you can use a `===` to compare. `this.state.bigObject === nextState.bigObject` instead of having to loop over each property. You can also write a method to do a shallowEqual to compare things, or use lodash/underscore.